# PyQt5 PDF border spacing in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5

I have generated a PDF using PyQt5 which is working perfectly fine. Am just looking to have a border spacing, unable to do that using layouts. Below is the code,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

    def printhtmltopdf(html_in, pdf_filename):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()

        def handle_pdfPrintingFinished(*args):
            print("finished: ", args)
            app.quit()

        def handle_loadFinished(finished):
            page.printToPdf(pdf_filename)

        page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(handle_pdfPrintingFinished)
        page.loadFinished.connect(handle_loadFinished)

        page.setZoomFactor(1)
        page.setHtml(html_in)

        app.exec()

    printhtmltopdf(
        result,    # raw html variable
        "file.pdf",
    )
```

Result is,

[image]

Expected result is as below having spaces in the beginning and end of the content.
Basically i need to have a padding on left, right, top and bottom

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load a custom CSS style sheet  in PyQt and apply this CSS file to the HTML content, resulting in the desired padding effect on elements.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

def printhtmltopdf(html_in, pdf_filename):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()

    def handle_pdfPrintingFinished(*args):
        print("finished: ", args)
        app.quit()

    def handle_loadFinished(finished):
        page.printToPdf(pdf_filename)

# added function
    def add_border_spacing():
        # Load a custom CSS style sheet with border spacing
        with open("style.css", "r") as file:
            css_content = file.read()
        page.setHtml(html_in, QtCore.QUrl().fromLocalFile(QtCore.QFileInfo("style.css").absoluteFilePath()))
        page.profile().scripts().insert(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineScript.DocumentCreation, css_content)

    page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(handle_pdfPrintingFinished)
    page.loadFinished.connect(handle_loadFinished)

    page.setZoomFactor(1)

    add_border_spacing() # apply function

    app.exec()

printhtmltopdf(
    result, 
    "file.pdf",
)
```

style css file

```
    border-spacing: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
```

style.css file is located in the same directory as your Python script.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388443/css-doesnt-work-in-qwebengineview-sethtml) answer. It load css using javascript.